# Inject React as a content script AND as a popup in a Chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I see many tutorials on how to inject a React app as a content script OR as browser action popup for a Chrome extension, but I want to do both: I want to be able to inject certain React components as content scripts, but then also have certain other components render as the popup when you click on the extension icon. Is this even possible?

Comment: interesting question, `react` script normally requires build, ex. babel etc. So in general it's pretty difficult to do it in the runtime. However if you already manage to transpire the script into javascript, as long as it's standalone, it should work.

Comment: Uhm, why is it a problem? Just make two entry points: one for the content script and another one for the popup.